# Can't import pyfits on python 3.7.6

Tags: python-3.x, pyfits

When I try to import pyfits I get the following message

```
/home/elihu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyfits/__init__.py:22: PyFITSDeprecationWarning: PyFITS is deprecated, please use astropy.io.fits PyFITSDeprecationWarning)  # noqa
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS focal and Python 3.7.6. Thanks!

Comment: The warning message gives you the answer: Use `astropy.io.fits` instead of `PyFITS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it looks like you're using Anaconda, you can run `conda install astropy`. The original pyfits package was merged into [`astropy.io.fits`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/latest/io/fits/index.html) so if you have existing code that uses `pyfits` you can replace the import statement with

```
import astropy.io.fits as pyfits
```

without changing much else. Note however that there may be additional deprecated or changed interfaces. PyFITS has not been updated as a separate package in over 5 years.